# Java API for Google AppEngine Endpoints error: Response Not Found

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I'm starting to develop a backend service for apps using Google AppEngine Cloud EndPoints.

I'm following the Google's tutorial on: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/hello_world

After I create the project using Maven in eclipse, it states the following errors:

Description Resource Path Location Type Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4:endpoints_get_discovery_doc (execution: default, phase: compile) pom.xml /TestApp line 133 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Description Resource Path Location Type Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.1:display-dependency-updates (execution: default, phase: compile) pom.xml /TestApp line 80 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Description Resource Path Location Type Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.1:display-plugin-updates (execution: default, phase: compile) pom.xml /TestApp line 80 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Nevertheless the project built, and it shows:

"404 OK

Hide headers -
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate content-encoding: gzip content-length: 29 content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 date: Wed, 17 Dec 2014 23:25:53 GMT expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT pragma: no-cache server: GSE vary: Origin, X-Origin

Not Found"

I have no clue what it might be, any thoughts or tips on building it?

Answer (score 0):

Although, I am answering this question pretty late but I faced same error and didn't find any solution so hope this helps somebody
I was following same tutorial. At first my project was not running with the new configuration. So I restarted the eclipse then project got build. After running project when I hit the URL it showed 404.
Later i realized another application was already running at port 8080. So I **changed the port number** It worked for me.